# В каком порту хранятся веб приложения?

Tags: сервер

Я новичок в программировании. И со вчерашнего дня меня мучает вопрос. Читал книгу про Servlet. Там говорится что любой сервер состоит из 16 bit (65535) портов. На один порт можно записать только одну программу. "A port represents a logical connection to a particular piece of software running on the server hardware.".

Выходит я записываю все веб приложения на свободные порты (Например 1003, 1004), так как на каждый порт можно записать только одну прогрымму, и запрашиваю данные с этого приложения через порт 80?

Заранее извиняюсь если терминолигия и вопрос не совсем корректен

Comment: Тоесть порт 80 я вообще не использую. Я записываю приложения на порт который отвечает  HTTP запросам. И запрашиваю напрямую через него?

Comment: Web приложения, особенно servlet-ы, обычно "хранятся" все на одном порту. Кроме порта у web-приложения есть например url. У каждого приложения свои url. Порт захватывает сервер приложений. К нему поступают запросы с url конкретного приложения. И сервер вызывает соответствующее url-у приложение. Таким нехитрым способом на одном порту может работать бесконечно много приложений.

Comment: @Sergey может, как ответ опубликуете?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Считаю в данном случае нужно более глубокое объяснение на пальцах. Я ещё не набрался такого экспириенса. Для этого нужен талант.